# Can I skip file validation when programmatically opening a workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I have a roughly 100MB-large Excel file that I am opening with this code that runs when a UserForm button is pressed:

```
Public Sub SelectButton_Click()
    fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Please Select a Report")
    If fNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Because this file is so big, it takes a while to validate before opening, and this validation makes up about half the time my entire macro takes to complete (I'm working in Excel 2013 and this file is not opening from a network or shared drive). If I open the file manually, then I get the option to skip validation after three seconds of validating. The problem with this is that it opens the file in Protected View, where I can't work with it.

**Using VBA, is there a way to "force skip" this time consuming validation while simultaneously avoiding Protected View?**

When Excel is completely closed, this warning/guideline appears in the bottom left of the opening splash screen:

[image]

---

When Excel is already open, this warning/guideline appears in the bottom right:

[image]

Comment: What kind of validations are you referring to? There are a few categories that come to mind. However, here are a few thoughts. You can prevent updates to external links by passing in a parameter when you use the open method. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx. You can turn off protected view by: https://support.smartvault.com/04Support/01Knowledge_Base/Turn_off_Protected_View_in_Excel_to_improve_performance_of_opening_Excel_documents_from_the_SmartVault_Drive. Lastly, if you just need to read some data from the file take a look at the OpenSchema method in ADO.

Comment: @RyanWildry I've added screenshots to display what I'm seeing re: validation. Thanks for the links and suggestions, I will check them out. I did consider just reading the data, comparing the necessary values, and storing the rows in an array, but I figured even that complexity was unnecessary for this business need.

Comment: I think this is office file validation. Here's a post on how to delete it. There's a registry entry you can change. https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/disable-microsoft-office-file-validation.4038038/. Also see this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2501584/microsoft-security-advisory-microsoft-office-file-validation-for-office-2003,-2007-office,-and-office-2010-april-12,-2011

Comment: Unfortunately those links are only useful for disabling the add-on which affects Office 2003, 2007, and 2010, while I'm working in an Office 2013 environment (which has File Validation baked in). I am also looking for something that VBA can handle on a per-macro basis rather than a per-computer basis; e.g. this solution would be implemented once in the VBA code and then would work on any computer that ran the macro. Changing application settings for each computer won't be an effective solution, even if it were possible.

Comment: Should be similar. Set the EnableOnLoad DWORD to be 0 at: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Excel\Security\FileValidation

Comment: Hi @TylerH , try using an .xlsb file which is lighter version of an .xlsm which may help the validation speed...

Comment: @TheSilkCode The file I'm loading is not a macro file, it is .xls (or .xlsx); I'm opening it via the code in my question, which *is* from a macro file.

Comment: @RyanWildry That does work, which is worth an upvote as an answer at least. I'll probably not accept it (at least not right away) in the hopes that someone can find a programmatic way to do that per-file rather than per-workstation.

Comment: You should be able to write a script to update that registry value. See: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/registry.htm

Comment: @RyanWildry I suppose I could, but editing the registry via VBA seems... well, terrible practice, at best.

Comment: Agreed, but I'm not seeing another way to do what's needed and achieve the desired outcome.

Comment: Is Application.FileValidation = msoFileValidationSkip is not working for you?

Comment: @cyboashu - wouldn't that still leave the file in Protected View?  (I've never used it, so that's a question, not a comment meaning "you're wrong")

Comment: No not for me,at least. But again my policies are dictated by my organization's IT people. so not sure how that will work on other machines. Easiest way to get rid of the protected view is to store and access the file from **trusted locations** only.

Comment: @cyboashu - The documentation says that it will open in Protected View if it **fails** the validation, so I guess "skipping" it isn't the same as "failing" (which, strictly speaking, it isn't - but I just thought it would have meant that "failing" = "not passing", and that "skipping" would mean it couldn't "pass").  I just tried a test and it seems like that is probably a valid answer.

Comment: @YowE3K If I manually skip validation on open, it also opens in Protected View.

Comment: @cyboashu That's also a good suggestion, I had forgotten about Trusted Locations. That will bypass the need for Office File Validation to run without a registry setting. There are several helpful answers in these comments that would be worthy of upvotes.

Comment: Have you tried to save your Excel file in *.xlsb format? The size of the file is minimized, then may be its opening will be faster

Comment: @D.O. It is the .xls(x) file that is 100MB large; the .xlsm file is the one that has the code doing the FileOpen, and it's only 100KB or so.

Comment: So save the .xlsx into .xlsb

Comment: @D.O. I was under the impression that xlsb was a binary alternative to xlsm, not xlsx. Does it work for both? At any rate, the xls(x) file is ouputted from another app, so it's not really a feasible workaround to expect the end user to open that file up and save it as .xlsb. That would probably take them longer to do than just waiting out the 15 seconds it takes to validate the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far there are two solutions that I've found to be useful for solving this problem, thanks to the comments above:

#### 1. Disabling Office Validation for Excel files in the Registry settings for Windows:

I prefer to use early binding, so I would suggest in the VBA editor window, opening the Tools window, selecting 'References...', and then checking the box next to 'Windows Script Host Object Model', and clicking OK. This will enable IntelliSense as you are writing your VBA:

```
Dim wsh As New WshShell
wsh.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Excel\Security\FileValidate\DisableEditFromPV", 0, "REG_DWORD"
Set wsh = Nothing
```

This will work for Excel 2013. If you have a different version of Office or Excel, you will use something other than `15.0` in your file path.

However, this method has the glaring problem of removing validation of any Excel file on your computer, even those that might have malicious code in them or that might run from dangerous locations, such as your Temp or Downloads folder.

Additionally, writing to the Windows Registry might be disallowed depending on your current environment or permissions. For that reason, I recommend a different solution:

#### 2. Setting the location of the Excel file to be a Trusted Location in Microsoft Excel:

1. It's possible to set a new Trusted Location in the Registry via VBA, but since this method is intended for use by those who can't access the registry, we won't get into that.

   To add the file's location (let's say it's the "Excel Files" folder in C:\) as a Trusted Location, first click the File tab and then click Options at the bottom of the File Menu:

   [image: Selecting Options on the Excel File Menu]
2. In the Excel Options window that opens up, click on Trust Center at the bottom of the side menu and then click the <kbd>Trust Center Settings</kbd> button that appears on the right:

   [image]
3. Finally, click the <kbd>Add new location...</kbd> option and enter `C:\Excel Files\` (or whatever your folder location is; you can even browse to it), and then click <kbd>OK</kbd>. You can also check the option to include subfolders if you want.

   [image]